# What does weighted cumulative frequency distribution mean?

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, weights

I have two sets of data (temperature and catch) and I am following a proposed method in an article I am reading on the empirical cumulative function (ECDF) analysis. Firstly, I have derived the ECDF for my temperature data using the ecdf function in R. The second step was to get the catch-weighted cumulative distribution for temperature, which I honestly cannot understand the concept.

$$
W(t)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y_i}{y}I_{\{x_i\}}
$$

where $y_i$ is the catch for day $i$; $y$ mean is the average of catch for all days and $I_{\{x_i\}}$  is the indication function.

How do I compute for this curve?

Comment: You refer to $y$ mean in the later comments, but it is not mentioned elsewhere in your question. Do you mean $\overline{y}$, and where should it be?

Comment: What part do you not understand? The indicator function will be equal to 1 if $x_i$ satisfies some condition and 0 if not. I dont know what that condition is or what $x_i$ but you should be able to determine that from your reference material.

Comment: @SimonHayward: yes, \overline{y}.it is the denominator of y_i. I want to get the catch-weighted cumulative curve, so what I did was to get the frac{y_i}{y} and multiply with the corresponding x_i (temperature measurement at day i) and tried ecdf in R (wrong result). What's the right approach in evaluating this expression. thanks much.

Comment: I've never heard of this, it is above my pay grade I suspect! I have work of my own to finish for now, but I will see if I can look it up later.

Comment: @jerad: from the article, the condition for indicator function is x <= t; 1 and 0 otherwise; t signifies the ordered observation from lowest to highest. I could not understand the t part (is it just the index: 1:n observation or the sorted actual temperature measurements?). If I want to prepare an input vector in R for ecdf function, what will I derived the input vector. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post a link to your article? I can't tell you what $t$ is without knowing more.

Comment: @jerad. This is the link to the article.http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2419.2008.00461.x/abstract. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: @ida1215, Thanks... you might want to edit your original post to include the link.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of base R suggestions, one for where the weights are integers but not too large and the second for where the weights are simply positive

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(temp=c(50,20,10,40), weight=c(3,1,4,2))

# unweighted empirical CDF
plot.ecdf(df$temp,
  main="unweighted ecdf")

# weighted empirical CDF if weights are positive integers or counts
plot.ecdf(rep(df$temp, df$weight),
  main="weighted ecdf 1 - using counts")

# weighted empirical CDF if weights are positive 
dfsorted <- df[order(df$temp), ]
dfsorted$cumfreq <- cumsum(dfsorted$weight) / sum(dfsorted$weight)
dfsorted2 <- dfsorted[rep(1:nrow(df), each=2),]
dfsorted2$cumfreq <- c(0,dfsorted2$cumfreq[-2*nrow(df)])
plot(dfsorted2$temp, dfsorted2$cumfreq, type="l",
  main="weighted ecdf 2 - general weights", xlab="temp", ylab="cumfreq")
```

So the unweighted ecdf looks like

[image]

and the first weighted ecdf looks like

[image]

and the second weighted ecdf looks like

[image]